# Is it possible to extend AWS Lambda with a new language?

Tags: aws-lambda

According to

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model-v2.html

I can write AWS Lambda functions in

- Node.js
- Python
- Java
- Go
- C#
- PowerShell

Can I extend the AWS Lambda framework with other languages?

Answer (score 0):

**You can write code for Lambda only in the languages specified by AWS.**

> However, as Lambda provides a Linux like architecture to run your
>   code, you can execute other codes(in other languages) as child
>   processes if supported by your primary language.

For example, you can run C code or executable files by spawning a child process from Node.js.